# "assignment" or "mission"? The job that a person does for their company in another city

Tags: vocabulary

What is the word used for referring to the job that a person does for their company in another place, city, etc. during a specific period of time?

Do we use "assignment" or "mission"? or another word?

Comment: *mission* and *assignment* both work. On the other hand, contrary to what Watercleave's answer describes, a company can send its employee as a part of their *mission*; and in armed force, allocating an *assignment* is quite common. Above all, the commonest phrase I have heard from the employees is *I'm here for my company's work.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "civilian" work, "assignment" is normally used. We would say that a person has been **assigned** to do something, or **assigned** to a location, and that they are **on assignment** somewhere.

The word "mission" is used for military, covert (spy) and other such kinds of "work". The word is also used in a religious (or at least Christian, I can't speak for the vocabulary of other groups) context for an outreach programme to a distant location.

---

Another, equally valid way to look at it is that while "assignment" can be used anywhere, "mission" implies a goal in an environment that is somehow hostile: hostile territory, a foreign country (hostile to a spy, but not to an accountant working at a company branch there), unexplored territory etc.

Comment: Another possible word is 'secondment' - a temporary transfer to another job or post within the same organization - which the Collins English Dictionary lists as 'British'. It is used in Australian English.